# How does an electron identify whether to absorb a photon of a certain wavelength or not in absorption spectrum?

Tags: spectroscopy, atomic-structure

How would an electron identify the specific photons of a certain wavelength which are to be absorbed in a Hydrogen atom while creating an absorption spectrum? Well, I was thinking of it like this-

Way-01: The electron will absorb any photon coming towards it regardless of its wavelength and jump. Then if the wavelength is the exact amount required to jump from one shell to another, then the electron simply jumps to the higher shell. Otherwise, it cannot find a shell and since electrons cannot exist in between shells, they simply re-emit that photon and we perceive the incident as if the photon weren't absorbed at all.

Way-02: The explanation given above is false and electrons choose the photons via some other mechanism

Now, my question is- is the "Way-01" correct? Or do electrons identify the photons via some other way? If so, then what is it?

Note: I'm only a high-schooler, so any relatively simple qualitative explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: “relatively simple qualitative explanation” There isn't one. You can come up with stories that seem to make intuitive sense to yourself, like your explanation above, but I doubt any of them will be close to reality, i.e. [quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule) and possibly [quantum electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics). Electrons can't exist in limbo and "choose" whether to re-emit a photon or not; they don't have a brain, they aren't sentient. It's fun, but incorrect, to anthropomorphise them.

Comment: [It's perhaps not the answer you want, but I do not mean it in a condescending manner at all, as I don't understand it *myself*. See also Feynman's famous quote: *"If you think you understand quantum mechanics, you don't understand quantum mechanics."*.]

Comment: I like Way-01. Slight modification: the electron gets vibrated, rather than absorbed, by any incoming photon and may just shift into a cavity (shell) where the vibration echoes just right. Coupled pendulums illustrate the transfer of energy from one item to an identical item, so with the substitution of photon energy for electron energy, you have a similar picture. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3c73d5GJ2V0

Comment: @JamesGaidis Don't confuse him further.

Comment: Well, actually, maybe some kind of resonance analogy might work...? It would quickly degenerate into a very circular description if I tried to explain it, but someone better than me could do it. I'll bow out...

Comment: I must reiterate what **orthocresol** said: don't even _start_ making up stories about quantum stuff. You don't yet have the right words for that, and won't have for a while. The explanations you come up with may be witty and colorful and all that, but they won't lead you in the right direction. For example, contrary to your "Way-01", the photon is decidedly not re-emitted. We know that because there are cases when a photon **is** genuinely re-emitted, and it behaves very differently then. To begin with, it "forgets" where it came from and has no reason to continue in the previous direction.

Comment: @Habib I agree with the others that some sort of intuitive classical will ultimately be misleading. However, if I were to offer one, it would be this: If you toss a handful of differently shaped objects such as spheres, cubes, prisms, etc. at circular hole the width of the sphere, how does the hold identify whether to allow an object through or not? I suppose you could say the hole will absorb the objects of the right size, and not interact with the others. For electrons, the measurement by which it will or won't interact with photons is energy.

Comment: The Bohr model of the atom is wrong. It's primitive and wrong. "However, because of its simplicity, and its correct results for selected systems, the Bohr model is still commonly taught to introduce students to quantum mechanics." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [OP..] How would an electron identify the specific photons of a certain wavelength which are to be absorbed in a Hydrogen atom while creating an absorption spectrum?

As discussed in the comments, this is an observed phenomenon. We can try to describe this observation in a way that we can make predictions, but that does not answer the questions "how?".

> [OP..] Otherwise, it cannot find a shell and since electrons cannot exist in between shells, they simply re-emit that photon and we perceive the incident as if the photon weren't absorbed at all.

There are processes that do something similar as the one you describe, but they involve observable events. When an atom scatters light, it scatters light of the same wavelength as the incoming light, but in all directions. There are also processes where the light is absorbed and then emitted again after a while (sometimes at different wavelength). What you suggest is an explanation for observing no interaction between the electron and the photon, and explaining it with an interaction (absorption and instant re-emission at the same wavelength in the same direction) that we can't observe.

You could have explanation models of the same flavor for many things that don't happen. For example, on a day it does not rain, I could say drop form in the clouds but instantly are destroyed again, so we can't observe them ever.

> Way-02: The explanation given above is false and electrons choose the photons via some other mechanism

As you can read in the comments, using the term "choose" for something electrons do is not so helpful. We know under what conditions the photon might get absorbed (not all of them are), but to go beyond that and explain the "how" or even "why" is difficult to impossible (and not taught in e.g. the 4-year college chemistry curriculum, as far as I know).

Comment: Since yesterday I was thinking on how to decently write this. The important part is to point out that something similar to way 2 exist but in an observable way. Plus 1. To OP: Still, one can put it even in more pictorial way. For instance, taking the photon as the anthropomorph does already a better job than way 1. It simply goes where it can, like a marble goes into hole in which it fits. The marble and the hole don't need to know it a priori (of course a marble falls also in bigger holes, the photon not.. This open the way to some of the scattering process mentioned above).